# Text Input not being assigned to Array items VB6

Tags: arrays, vb6

I have been using Visual Basic 6 to try and assign the values from a text input box into an array item, using the `ReDim` function so as to assign a new text input to the next array item.

Heres the code:

```
Public EquationArray() As String
Public a As Integer

Public Sub StoreCurve()

    ReDim EquationArray(a)
    EquationArray(a) = frmMain.txtExpression.Text
    ReDim EquationArray(a + 1)
    a = a + 1

End Sub
```

The values in the text input box are equations. I have not set a value to 'a', as I assume the value for 'a' is automatically 0.

When I test if the values from the textbox have been set to the array item, nothing comes up. If I remove the ReDim line (line 8) however, the text input value appears to have set to the array item.

Any help here on what is going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I am not familiar with VB 6 anymore I guess you can fix your problem by using [Preserve](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266231(v=vs.60).aspx) when resizing your arrays, i.e. change your `ReDim` lines to include `Preserve` like so

```
ReDim Preserve EquationArray(a + 1)
```